# Papermill With Cronjob: Error: papermill is a directory and can't find filepath

Tags: terminal, cron, filepath, papermill

I am trying to execute a jupyter notebook with crontab and papermill and cannot find the correct filepath to give the crontab to run papermill.

Here is what I have currently

```
#on one line:
0 * * * * /path-to-papermill/papermill 
/Users/username/path-to-code/notebook.ipynb 
/Users/username/path-to-code/output_notebook.ipynb 
> /tmp/stdout.log 2> /tmp/stderr.log
```

The error I get is `papermill is a directory`

I used `pip show papermill` to grab the filepath but I checked and it is just a directory. Where is the papermill file itself, or what file am I running when, in the terminal, I can run `papermill notebook.ipynb output.ipynb`?

How do I make the command run?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong command to find the file, I had to use `which`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).